# can I use the img sizes attribute to define the intended height of image rather than the width?

Tags: html, responsive-images

My image should always be rendered with a specific *height* of `500px`

```html
<picture>
  <source
    srcset="
      small-image.webp 500h,
      bigger-image.webp 1000h,
      huge-image.webp 2000h
    "
    media="all"
    type="image/webp"
    sizes="500px"
  >
  <img src="fallback-image.webp" alt="An image with a height of 500px">
</picture>
```

But the [sizes spacification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#sizes-attribute) states:

> The `<source-size-value>` gives the intended layout width of the image. The author can specify different widths for different environments with `<media-condition>`s.

So `sizes` can only specify widths?

Comment: Related: [HTMLImageElement.sizes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/sizes)